# nested parameter destructuring with default values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to init my parameters so I can run `getProducts()`, as well as

```
getProducts({
  query: {},
  p: {
    offset: 0,
    sort: {
      _id: 1
    },
    limit: 25,
    count: 0
  }
})
```

. So far, only the latter works, using this function :

```
getProducts({
  query = {},
  pagination: {
    offset = 0,
    sort = {
      _id: 1
    },
    limit = 25
  }
}) {
  console.log(offset, limit, sort)
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple on initialisation, but can't figure out what, even with the MDN docs.

Comment: "The latter works" what works exactly? Because nothing in your code is working... The console.log closed with brace instead of parentheses, is it a function declaration because it got no Function keyword. It also cannot be a call, since it has braces after... Please show us the right defintion, the way you call it when it works, the way you call it when it does not.

Comment: ugh, sth went wrong with the auto indent, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not following the Object destructuring syntax as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), check this:

```js
function getProducts({query, pagination: {offset, limit, sort}} = {query: {},pagination: {offset: 0, limit: 25, sort: {_id: 1}}}){
  console.log(query, offset, limit, sort);
}

getProducts()

getProducts({query: {}, pagination: {offset: 10, limit: 50, sort: {_id: -1}}})
```